# Merge/join two dataframes based on shortest distance of longitudes and latitudes

Tags: r, dataframe, fuzzyjoin

I have one `df1` that has `800` rows and the other `df2` that has `9 million` rows. Both have latitude and longitude and the `df2` has some more columns that I need to add to `df1` based on shortest distance as lat and lon do not mach exactly in both `dataframes`. I used `goe_join` from `Fuzzyjoin` package but get errors.

Summary of `df1`:

```
summary(df1)
          lat             lon           
 Min.   :25.39   Min.   :-124.62   
 1st Qu.:36.20   1st Qu.:-104.94    
 Median :40.63   Median : -84.15   
 Mean   :39.32   Mean   : -89.44    
 3rd Qu.:42.08   3rd Qu.: -73.97    
 Max.   :48.73   Max.   : -67.27
```

Summary of `df2`:

```
summary(df2)
lon               lat                    x1                 x2                x3 
 Min.   :-124.73   Min.   :24.98   Min.   :-2230806   Min.   :-1569579   Min.   :     0.0  
 1st Qu.:-110.13   1st Qu.:34.78   1st Qu.:-1126720   1st Qu.: -508033   1st Qu.:   670.8  
 Median : -99.17   Median :39.06   Median : -263314   Median :  -15116   Median :  1507.5  
 Mean   : -99.17   Mean   :38.97   Mean   : -239487   Mean   :  -30086   Mean   :  2856.3  
 3rd Qu.: -88.94   3rd Qu.:43.25   3rd Qu.:  578810   3rd Qu.:  466600   3rd Qu.:  3354.7  
 Max.   : -66.97   Max.   :49.38   Max.   : 2122143   Max.   : 1270878   Max.   :395131.9
```

Here is my code:

```
merged.dfs <- geo_join(df1, df2, by = NULL, method = "haversine", mode = "left", max_dist = 1)
```

Here is the error I get:

```
Joining by: c("lat", "lon") 

Error in fuzzy_join(x, y, multi_by = by, multi_match_fun = match_fun, : long vectors not supported yet: ../../src/include/Rinlinedfuns.h:522
```

I appreciate your help!

Comment: I think *"long vectors not supported"* is both clear and unavoidable. Break your 9M row frame into smaller frames and repeat all 800 across your fragmented-9M frame. You'll need to keep some measure of distance in the merged frame so that you can take all of the appended columns (for each original point) and determine which to keep.

Comment: BTW: if you want actual coding help, you'll need to provide sample data. Giving the summary is informative statistically but not programming-wise: I cannot create sample data that matches your data based on that alone. Consider `dput(head(x))` for each. Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269, https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.